# RequestDispatcher dumping html page inside input field

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

How do I avoid the dispatcher from pushing the entire HTML page into an input field.

Below is the code...it's getting attached to my session variable and dumping the rest of the page inside the input field.

Servlet:

```
    Cookie sCookie = new Cookie("id", id);
    response.addCookie(sCookie);
    HttpSession session= request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("id",id);

    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/student.jsp");
    rd.include(request, response);
```

HTML side (Student.jsp is being dumped into below input field):

```
 <input name="id" id="id" value=<%=id%>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("path to page").forword(...);
```

instead of `rd.include(...);`

Give a try to code

```
session.setAttribute("id", id.getValue());
```

Comment: Already tried, rd.forward(request, response);    Not working.

Comment: Cookie class also have methods. In this you are passing object as value, not the cookie data as value

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  Ended up doing:  result = result.substring(0, result.indexOf('\n'));